# How to use a module/class function/method in a different module/class without importing the module/class or knowing the file architecture in Python?

Tags: python, import

I'm a somewhat of an intermediate Python programmer but there's something that's been bugging me for a while. I'm trying to unify code to make it reusable by many projects. The problem I am facing is how to access function (or methods for that matter) by a certain class (or procedural code) without importing the module/class. I want my code to not know about the existence of other files/modules.
Here's an example.

Imagine I have a the following file architecture for my project (that would be reused by other project but with a slight variation):

- Main Folder

  - main.py
  - Folder1>module1>func1
  - Folder2>module2>func2 (func2 calls func1, let's say func1 is a common math operation, like finding whether a point is on a plane within a tolerance)

Now, in main.py, I import both module1 and module2

let's say I have a function in main.py that calls func2 as such

```
## In main.py
def call_func1():
    module2.func2()

## In module1.py
def is_point_on_plane():
    print("testing")
    
## In module2.py
def func2():
    is_point_on_plane() ## This is a function that is currently in module1
```

Now, I don't want module1 or module2 to know anything about each other, or even that the other exists. I'm trying to avoid any imports.

The way I'm working around this is to pass **is_point_on_plane** as a parameter to func2 in **main.py**

```
def call_func1():
    fcToCall = module1.is_point_on_plane
    module2.func2(fcToCall)

## In module1
def is_point_on_plane():
    print("testing")

## In module2
def func2(fcToCall):
    fcToCall()
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. A more Pythonic way. In whichever case, I need module1 and module2 to be completely independent and avoid any imports.

Answer (score 0):

you could import the file name of the project you want for example:
"if my want to use another def function of a file called 'main.py' then i will write

```
import main
main.call_func1()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't resolve my issue. All my operations are in main. My main issue is accessing functions from module1 in module2 without them know about each other, all while avoiding any imports.